# Introductory book on time-frequency analysis?

Tags: time-frequency

I'm looking for an introductory book to time-frequency analysis. The book should be practical in nature and not mathematics heavy. Suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you need to learn? Every book on time-frequency analysis I've ever seen is quite mathematical.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this book:

[Understanding Digital Signal Processing, Richard G. Lyons](http://www.amazon.fr/Understanding-Digital-Signal-Processing-Edition/dp/0137027419)

This book explains the basics concepts of digital signal processing, which includes time-frequency analysis, in a very intuitive way.

Answer (score 1):

To be frank, time-frequency analysis is mathematical in nature. So there will always be some mathematics involved.

I've read a few DSP books over the years, none of them comes even close to the clarity of explanation in the following book, which is available for free online:

[The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/).

You would though, have to take it step at a time (I guess you can stop reading at chapter 8). These concepts don't really have a 'quick fix' type of explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend "An Introduction to Time-Frequency and Wavelet Transforms" by Shie Qian. It covers Fourier, Gabor, Wavlet and Quadratic representations. It does not go into each area very deeply - but gives you and idea and you can then go into each area as you see fit. It does contain some mathematics, but not overly so.

Having some foundation in linear algebra principles i.e. bases, orthogonality etc, will be useful. Wavelets are usually approached through multi-rate techniques (decimation and interpolation).

There are also some tutorial like articles in the IEEE publications. Qian has one in the IEEE Signal Processing Magazine. Leonard Cohen has one in the Proceedings that focuses on linear and quadratic (STFT, Wigner-Ville) representations.

Another text is :
"Fundamentals of Wavelets" by Goswani and Chan. While it is geared towards Wavelets, it covers STFT, Gabor and Wigner-Ville as well. The first chapter covers the basic linear algebra and vector space concepts you'll need to know.

Answer (score 0):

I have recommended Signal Analysis Time, Frequency, Scale and Structure by 
Ronald L. Allen and Duncan W. Mills
I read this book.